# Read a file created in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi

I'll port a old Delphi application to C# and need help to read the files that Delphi has created.

My C # program will use serialization to read and write files, but the program must also be able to read the old Delphi-created files and that's what I need help with.

*In short, I need help to read a file created with BlockWrite*

Delphi code to create the file:

```
sys: SystemRecord;

procedure SaveSystem;
var
  fileType,
  fileVersion: Byte;
  IORes:       Integer;
  fileName:    String;
  f:           File;
begin
  fileType:=1;    { system file }
  fileVersion:=1; { Version on the file}
  fileName:=GetSystemFileName;
  {$I-}
  if IOResult = 0 then;  { Read IOResult }
  Assign(f,fileName);
  Rewrite(f,1);
  IORes:=IOResult;
  if IORes = 0
  then begin
    BlockWrite(f,fileType,1);
    BlockWrite(f,fileVersion,1);
    BlockWrite(f,sys,SizeOf(sys));
    Close(f);
    IORes:=IOResult;
  end;
  {$I+}
  if IORes <> 0
  then begin
    LogHnd(_SaveSystem,'');
    MainForm.SetInfo(INFO_SaveSystem_ERR,'');
  end
  else begin
    MainForm.SetInfo(INFO_SaveSystem_OK,'');
  end;
end;
```

Delphi code to read the file:

```
procedure LoadSystem;
var
  fileType,
  fileVersion: Byte;
  IORes:       Integer;
  fileName:    String;
  f:           File;
  fileOK:      Boolean;
begin
  fileOK:=FALSE;
  fileName:=GetSystemFilename;
  {$I-}
  if IOResult = 0 then;  { Read IOResult }
  Assign(f,fileName);
  Reset(f,1);
  IORes:=IOResult;
  if IORes = 0 then begin
    BlockRead(f,fileType,1);
    BlockRead(f,fileVersion,1);
    IORes:=IOResult;
    if (fileType = 1) AND (IORes = 0) then begin
      case fileVersion of
        1: begin
          BlockRead(f, sys, SizeOf(sys));
          IORes:=IOResult;
          if IORes = 0 then if EOF(f) then fileOK:=TRUE;
        end; { 1 }
      end; { case }
    end;
    Close(f);
    IORes:=IOResult;
    if IORes <> 0 then; { Skip waring  }
  end
  else begin { system file missing => load default settings }
    InitSystem;
    fileOK:=TRUE;
  end;
  {$I+}
  if (NOT fileOK)
  then begin
    InitSystem;          { Read error => Load default settings }
    LogHnd(_LoadSystem,''); { To event log }
    MainForm.SetInfo(INFO_LoadSystem_ERR,'');
  end
  else MainForm.SetInfo(INFO_LoadSystem_OK,'');
end;
```

The structures/enum to save:

```
SystemRecord = record
    verk: Array[1..MAXVERK] of VerkRecord;
    activeVerk: Integer;
    com: ComRecord;
    hastighet: THastighet;
    tipStatus:  Array[1..MAXTIP] of TipStatusRecord;
    brus: Integer; { 1..50 }
    TIPcolor: Array[1..3,1..2] of Byte;
    dummy: Array[1..494] of Byte; { For backward compatibility }
  end;

VerkRecord = record
    active:    boolean;
    name:      string[40];
    shortname: string[10];
    formula:   string[100];
    antalKanaler: Array[1..MAXTIP] of Integer; 
    sondXref: Array[1..MAXTIP,1..MAXKANAL] of Integer;
    TOCtime: Array[1..MAXTIP,1..MAXKANAL] of TDateTime;
    BOCtime: Array[1..MAXTIP,1..MAXKANAL] of TDateTime;
    blockerad: Array[1..MAXSOND] of Boolean; 
    tipIsDigit: Boolean; 
    sondLength: Integer; 
    power: Integer;     
    dummy: Array[1..200] of Byte; { For backward compatibility }
  end;

  ComRecord = record
    port: Word;
    baud: Word;
    stop: Word;
    data: Word;
    par:  Word;
  end;

TipStatusRecord = record
    position: 1..9; 
    riktning: 0..2; 
    ATIP: 1..6;     
    ATCU: 1..4;     
    SelfTest: 0..1; 
    ATCUStatus: 0..1;
    measurePos: Integer; 
    kanal: Integer;
  end;

THastighet = (normal, brus, dubbel, trippel, snabb);
```

Comment: Use whatever C# raw binary write functionality you are comfortable with. BTW this source does not completely define the file format. The records are not packed and packing is not specified otherwise, and thus the packing of the records is defined by the compiler settings in the IDE, outside the source

Comment: How do I now how the records are packed? Can I see it in the project file? I dont have the IDE to Delphi.

Comment: The declaration of the record type itself. If the `packed` key is not used then it's not packed.

Comment: No, packed key is not used. Is the code that "Matthias Alleweldt"
wrote correct then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is written with a pre unicode delphi version this gives you a starting point:

```
const int MAXVERK = 10;
const int MAXTIP = 5;
const int MAXKANAL = 3;

private void LoadSystem() {
  BinaryReader reader;

  reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("E:\\test.dat"));

  if (reader.ReadByte() != 1) {
    throw new Exception("Wrong file type");
  }

  if (reader.ReadByte() != 1) {
    throw new Exception("Wrong file version");
  }

  ReadSystemRecord(reader);    
}

private void ReadSystemRecord(BinaryReader Reader) {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXVERK; ++i) {
    ReadVerkRecord(Reader);
  }
  Int32 activeVerk = Reader.ReadInt32();
  ReadComRecord(Reader);
  byte hastighet = Reader.ReadByte();  // TODO: convert byte to the enum
  //...
}

private void ReadVerkRecord(BinaryReader Reader) {
  bool active = Reader.ReadByte() != 0;
  string name = ReadDelphiString(Reader, 40);
  string shortname = ReadDelphiString(Reader, 10);
  string formula = ReadDelphiString(Reader, 100);
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXTIP; ++i) {
    Int32 antalKanaler = Reader.ReadInt32();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXTIP; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXKANAL; ++j) {
      Int32 sondXref = Reader.ReadInt32();
    }
  }
  //...
}

private void ReadComRecord(BinaryReader Reader) {
  Int16 port = Reader.ReadInt16();
  Int16 baud = Reader.ReadInt16();
  Int16 stop = Reader.ReadInt16();
  Int16 data = Reader.ReadInt16();
  Int16 par = Reader.ReadInt16();
}

private string ReadDelphiString(BinaryReader Reader, int Length) {
  byte strlength = Reader.ReadByte();
  return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Reader.ReadBytes(Length), 0, strlength);
}
```

Not a complete reader and without any error handling. You have to add your C# data sotrage, the missing values and the TDateTime/Enum conversions. But this should be not verry difficult. Perhaps you have to test the value sizes in delphi.

Comment: For the two dimensional arrays, in what order are the bytes stored?

Comment: @magol: I added the sondXref reading to show the array organization of the two dimensional array.